# Some Connect terminology

Tags: node.js, express

Here are three pieces of terminology used in documentation relating to ConnectJS for NodeJS that keeps getting used, but that I don't completely undertand:

1) views and controllers

2) partials and collections

3) Middleware

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start from the bottom up.

## Level 0: built-in http module

In the beginning, there is node.js's built-in [http.Server](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http.Server) written by Ryan Dahl. You write a `function(req, res)`, and Node will call your function each time a new connection is accepted:

```
// Hello world HTTP server using http module:
var http = require('http');
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello, world.');
});
app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

## Level 1: Connect

[Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/), written by Tim Caswell, is simply a subclass of http.Server that makes it easier to organize your code. Instead of writing a single callback that handles every request, you chain together some **middleware**. Each middleware is a `function(req, res, next)` that handles the request if possible, or calls `next(error)` if it did not finish handling the user's request. The middleware handlers are called in the order of their `use`; you should call the catch-all `app.use(connect.errorHandler())` at the end.

One important middleware is the **router**, which allows you to filter some middleware based on a pattern of the URL path. The [syntax for the route patterns](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware) is based on ruby's Sinatra routes. When I use the filter `/hello/:name`, `req.params.name` will be set to the matching part of the URL.

```
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect.createServer();
app.use(connect.favicon());
app.use(connect.logger());,
app.use(connect.router(function(app) {
  app.get('/hello/:name', function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        throw new Error('Random error!');
      }
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Hello, ' + req.params.name);
    } catch (e) {
      return next(e);
    }
  });
}));
app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

In Connect, every handler is middleware! You use whichever functionality you need like bodyParser or cookieParser, and your own business logic is also a middleware function with the same signature `function(req, res, next)`. The [connect homepage](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) gives a list of the built-in middleware.

## Level 2: Express.js

Express's http server, written by TJ Holowaychuk, is in turn a subclass of Connect that forces the Sinatra style more. In Connect, there was no magic you didn't ask for, but in Express, the router and qs parser (which sets `req.query`) are automatically `use`d. The router syntax is cleaned up; you call `app.get`, `app.post`, etc. directly (and the router is positioned at the first call) rather than putting them inside a function.

Express also contains many other [well-documented](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) features and helper functions to extend app, req, and res.

One feature of Express is `res.render`, which renders the given template file (relative to `app.set('views')` or $PWD/views) using the template engine implied by the extension, and `res.partial`, which calls render on each element of a collection (which is just any arraylike object). But I haven't used this optional feature; if you don't care for express's templates you can just `res.send` data yourself.

Comment: Thanks yonran! One question: What is a "qs parser"?

Comment: `qs` is the node.js built in `qs` module (Query String) which has a `parse` method you can use for HTTP query string parsing.  http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/querystring.html#querystring.parse

Comment: I'm pretty sure connect (as of April 2013) ships with no router. There's a middleware called urlrouter that behaves the way you describe.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some comments.  If you have more specific questions, we can try to address them.

1) views and controllers

Views just means a template that can be used to render a response, which is usually HTML but could be plain text or some other format.  There are many different templating syntaxes and systems out there.  Some work in NodeJS as well as in web browsers.  That's all there is to views.

Controllers are the "C" in the MVC design pattern and are responsible as an intermediary between views and models.  They are basically the glue that handles some basic things like formatting choices that don't belong in the model code.

2) partials and collections

(Side comment, these are really part of [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), not Connect, but they are sibling libraries)

Partials is a document template representing a small portion or snippet of a document, as opposed to a complete HTML document.  Partials can be included by other templates and are often re-used by multiple containing templates.  Collections go hand in hand with them.  For example, you might have a partial to display a "President" object and in that partial you'd have markup for a photo, dates he served as president, political party, etc.  You could use that same partial throughout your site whenever you wanted to display a "President" record/object.  If you had a collection of several "President" objects, "collections" give you an easy way to say "render a president partial for each president object in this list".

3) middleware

The way connect handles responding to HTTP requests is to route the request through a series of functions called middleware.  Each middleware function adheres to a basic API of `(req, res, next)` and a few behavioral requirements.  Each piece of middleware can do one specific bit of processing, then when it's done, call `next()` to tell connect to move on to the next middleware function in the chain.  Connect comes with a bunch of middleware modules which you can see [on github](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/tree/master/lib/middleware).  Middleware can do whatever it wants. For example, parse JSON request bodies, search the filesystem for a matching static file to serve, check for session cookies, log to a log file, and so on. This design makes it really easy to re-use code as well as to combine separate middleware functions in novel combinations. Some middleware functions deal with parsing and processing the request, some deal with generating the response. Typically you can find existing middleware functions that do a lot of request processing (parsing, logging, decoding, converting, etc), and you provide your own middleware to actually render the response, which is also usually the last middleware in the chain.

Comment: Thanks Peter. You account of the use of `next()` is somewhat different than what yonran (see below) has to say, namely that `next(error)` is called if a middleware fails to complete its tasks.

Comment: @yonran is probably correct, here.  In the Express guide, he calls `next(error)` in the case of an unauthorized request, so that's probably better.  I'll edit my answer.